# socket programming connect multiple client to one server and list them C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, pthreads

Hi I really new to tcp socket programming I want to connect multiple client to one server using thread and once each client connect the server. we able to view that who(client) is connected to this server.

I was thinking to create the struct to hold client record on both client.c and server.c and once client is connected we will use `send(sock , (void *)&package , sizeof(struct USER) , 0` to passed structure to server.c and in server.c we also create same struct once server receive data `recv(sock, (void *)&package, sizeof(struct USER), 0);`server will store those data into struct but HOW? I try the result is when I connected multiple client one called User1 and other one called User2 then I try to print out the strut result is..

display on client 1

```
USER[0]: User1
USER[1]: (NULL)
```

display on client 2

```
USER[0]: (NULL)
USER[1]: User2
```

can anyone please help

Thank you so much

Comment: You dare to show the client's and the server's sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typical for multiple clients to connect to a single server. I'm not sure what information you're wanting to pass from each client to the server, but if it's something like the client's ip address or network settings, this is already provided by the client to the server when attempting to connect. A more in depth study of the TCP/IP protocol may be a good idea. There are a number of good tutorials and examples available.

If you're trying to share some other information over the network, once a connection is established, you can pass whatever you want over the sockets. This is all dependent on what your application is doing, which isn't specified.